# Exception: Invalid argument: http://[object%20Object] in Google Apps Script trigger. (It's working when I run it manually)

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a script in Google Apps Script to call an external api. It's all working fine when I run it from the script view and from the UI (Used spreadsheet.addMenu). But now I configured a trigger so the script can run every 24 hours.

The strange thing is, I get an error when the script is scheduled, which is this one:

```
Exception: Invalid argument: http://[object%20Object]
at accessProtectedResource(Exact auth:43:28)
at getAllInvoicesFromExact(Exact calls:14:15)
```

The argument should be the endpoint url I'm using. And again, it's working fine when I run it manually.

I would expect that it also should be working when I schedule the same script/function.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I think that in your question when you provide your current script for correctly replicating your current issue, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Need [mcve]. The error means  you're concatenating arrays or other objects instead of strings.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.

If you configure a trigger and choose a function with parameters, the first parameter is replaced by a parameter called 'e'.

Fixed it by adding 'e' to the parameters.

Changed

```
function getAllInvoicesFromExact(next, arr) {
```

To:

```
function getAllInvoicesFromExact(e, next, arr) {
```